# Cordova APNS background pass through

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am having problem with IOS push notification with Cordova performing a background pass through.

I am using https://github.com/ToniKorin/PushPlugin

I am trying to use the push notification to trigger a Javascript function on the background. But at the moment it isnt triggering it.

I have used exactly the same code as theirs, not sure if it is a permission problem, or if i need another plugin for background mode to work, i am not even sure where to look.

Edit
I added this in my Info.plist and it is in the plugin's xml

```
 <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: iOS apps don't run code when they are on background unless you registered them for certain background modes (geolocation, etc)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but i think that plugin has that in the xml, i put it in the edit. Not sure if thats the part you meant.

Comment: that is only for silent notifications, silent notifications should have content-available key on the push payload

Comment: Yer, i am trying to do a silent notification, (or just to receive a push notification and it triggers a Javascript on the background automatically). Not sure what the content-available key is. Because on that plugin, the authors never mentioned that. I am receiving the push notifications, but it isnt triggering the javascript in the background.

Comment: A silent push need that key, you have to do that on the server

Comment: Yer it was that tag.....omg thanks so much, if you want, write it as an answer and i will accept it, and it will give you a few points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only silent notifications can execute code on background.

A silent notification should have the `content-available` key on their push notification payload

Example of push payload to send a silent notification

```
{
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        sound : ""
    };
}
```